# ListView filter search with FutureBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am a beginner of flutter programming. i got a problem for search feature of listview when i use future builder, when i type a letter it change the list for a second, but back to all list data after a second. i dont know what's the error, because there is no warning or errors only. i stack on this code, please helpppppppppppppppp......

this is my code, 
[Default list data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vqen.jpg)
[when i type letters, the list back again after a seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fjGC.jpg)

```
List mydata;
  List unfilterData;

  Future loadJsonData() async {
    List data = json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('Json/indomodel.json'));
    setState(() {
      mydata = data;
      this.unfilterData = mydata;
    });
    return data;
  }

  Widget mylist() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: loadJsonData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.amber),
          ));
        else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              return Card(
                elevation: 0.3,
                child: ListTile(
                  // leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.adjust),),
                  title: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SelectableText(
                            mydata[index]['word'],
                            // data[index]['word'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.deepPurple.shade800),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "My Kamus",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        mydata[index]['trans'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontSize: 13.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  searchData(str) {
    var strExist = str.length > 0 ? true : false;

    if (strExist) {
      var filterData = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < unfilterData.length; i++) {
        String word = unfilterData[i]['word'];
        if (word.contains(str)) {
          filterData.add(unfilterData[i]);
        }
      }

      setState(() {
        this.mydata = filterData;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        //
        this.mydata = this.unfilterData;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are calling `loadJsonData()` in the `FutureBuilder`, so when you call `setState()` the `loadJsonData()` will be called again.

What you should do is to call `loadJsonData()` once, in the `initState()`, save the future into a variable and use that variable on the `FutureBuilder`, like this:

```
Future _future;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _future = loadJsonData();
}
```

And in the `FutureBuilder` do this:

```
future: _future,
```

---

**Note:** since you need to filter the list it's okay to save the list to `mydata` and then use `mydata` in the `ListView.builder()`, just make sure to change this part to avoid confusion:

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
```

should be:

```
itemCount: mydata.length,
```

**Suggestions:**

- It's a good practice to specify the correct types for `Future` and `List`
  so you can access to the properties without warnings, in your case
  would be like this: `Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>` and
  `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.
- It's not good to call `setState()` from a future because the widget
  could be disposed and cause errors, you could set the list inside the
  `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: thank you. it's work. thanks for the answer and the suggests. i can't upvote, my point not enough yet. but i accept the answer. thanks

Comment: @pablo I came across your suggestion, and it helped me today. But I have a followup question. How do you set the inside inside the FutureBuilder to avoid using `setState()` in `FutureBuilder`